# How to declare variable inside react function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I'm having some difficulty setting variables inside my handleSubmit function. `this.props.posts` is an array of objects coming from redux. I simply want to grab a single post object that matches with the id of the prop I passed in. I think my confusion lies in not quite understanding what I'm actually supposed to be returning here. Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
const  post  = 
  this.props.posts.map((el, i) => {
    if (el.id === this.props.id) {
      return el
    }
  })
console.log(post)
this.props.dispatch(updatePost(this.state.post))
this.props.closeForm()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` isn't what you're looking for.  You should use the [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to locate the object by id.

```
const  post  = this.props.posts.find(el => el.id === this.props.id)
```

or something like that.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!